# Multiple selection Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a class named summary and it contains a lot of differents tags like 'p', 'h2', 'img', 'li' etc...

What I want to do is a search using that criteria. I've tried using select and find_all with no luck.

Select: `data = soup.select('summary p')` but I cant include more than one tag at once eg: h2

Find_all: `data = soup.find_all(['p', 'h2'])` here I can pass a list and it finds all tags, but I don't know how to narrow the search to the `summary` class

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with `find_all()` is correct. You just have to pass the class as an attribute to the `find_all()`. Like this:

```
data = soup.find_all(['p', 'h2'], attrs={'class':'summary'})
```

It is documented [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

Comment: Using `soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'article-summary'})` it works, but if I add the tags `p` and `h2` it doesn't return anything... The point is that inside `summary` there are more classes like sharing stuff that I do not want, and all this data is followeb by an `a` tag.

Comment: Now I'm doing this: `data = soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'article-summary'})` then `for ps in data: p = ps.find_all(['p', 'h2', 'img'], recursive=False) print p`. But it is getting all tags inside that class like `h3`, `li` etc...

Comment: Link your html source and expected output, so we can help better

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/d3uCN2px. It is the content of a blog and I want to extract that content: p, h2, h3, img, iframe, li... The important data is afer ` <!-- .article-metadata -->` Thank you!